# java application to read information from ARIN RESTful Web Services

Tags: java, rest, service, web, restlet

I am trying to create a java application to read the information from ARIN using an IP Address. I see ARIN is using RESTful Web Services to get the IP information but I am not sure what I need to do to start. Some people are talking about `RESTLET`, other people about `JAX-RS`,etc. Can you please help me to take me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Being a bit more elaborate helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restlet also has a client API to interact with a remote RESTful application. See the classes Client, ClientResource for more details. For this, you need to have following jar files from Restlet distribution:

- org.restlet: main Restlet jar
- org.restlet.ext.xml: Restlet support of XML
- org.restlet.ext.json: Restlet support of JSON. In this case, the JSON jar present in libraries folder is also required.

If I use the documentation located at this address https://www.arin.net/resources/whoisrws/whois_api.html#whoisrws. Here is a simple Restlet code you can use:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN");
Representation repr = cr.get();
// Display the XML content
System.out.println(repr.getText());
```

or

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN.txt");
Representation repr = cr.get();
// Display the text content
System.out.println(repr.getText());
```

Restlet also provides some support at XML level. So you can have access to hints contained in the XML in a simple way, as described below:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN");
Representation repr = cr.get();
DomRepresentation dRepr = new DomRepresentation(repr);
Node firstNameNode = dRepr.getNode("//firstName");
Node lastNameNode = dRepr.getNode("//lastName");
System.out.println(firstNameNode.getTextContent()+" "+lastNameNode.getTextContent());
```

Note that you can finally handle content negotiation (conneg) since it seems supported by your REST service:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/KOSTE-ARIN");
Representation repr = cr.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

In this case, your representation object contains JSON formatted data. In the same way than the DomRepresentation, there is a JsonRepresentation to inspect this representation content.

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: Can you suggest a url to get the whois from ip address.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't seem to understand very well what REST is (sorry if I'm mistaken!). Restlet and JAX-RS are both server-side related.

You probably need something like [jersey-client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html). This is a library which helps to interact with RESTful webservices.
You could also usa plain Java libraries to make HTTP calls to the webservice. REST is tightly bound to its implementation protocol. This means that if the webservice is implemented in HTTP (most likely is) you don't need anything fancy to interact with it. Just HTTP.

I strongly encourage you to learn more about REST and HTTP itself.

Comment: Now I am in the right direction. Thank you for the information!

Comment: By initial design choice, Restlet Framework has a consistent/unified client and server API!